# Magento Shopsystem SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sql, magento, transactions, magento-1.9

im using Magento-Shopsystem 1.9.0.1.
A Transaction is failing occuring error message below:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`deko_production`.`sales_flat_order_payment`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_PAYMENT_PARENT_ID_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_order` (`entity_id`)

Does someone know what that means?

Thank you in advance

Hakan

Comment: The error message says it all. You are trying to set a parent_id that does not exists in the column entity_id in the sales_flat_order table.

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key reference in the table `deko_production`.  This specifies that any value of `parent_id` must already exist in `sales_flat_order.entity_id`.

You have attempted an `insert` or `update` where the value of `deko_production(parent_id)` is not a valid value.  Hence you are getting an error.